# how do i get my balls to move down the canvas after a short period of time?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my balls, in the array, to move directly down the canvas after a short period of time, one after the other to equal exactly 100 balls dropped. I included all of my code to try and show more of what i want the program to do. 
Really the balls spawn and a user controls the paddle scoring points for each ball hit. Their are radio buttons that can be checked to make the balls fall faster or slower. 
Im just stuck on getting the balls to move down the canvas one at a time.

```
var posY = 0;
var spawnRateOfDescent = 2;
var spawnRate = 500;
var lastSpawn = -1;
var balls = [100];
var startTime = Date.now();
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function checkRadio() {
    if (document.getElementById("moderate").checked == true) {
        spawnRate = 250;
    } else if (document.getElementById("hard").checked == true) {
        spawnRate = 100;
    } else if (document.getElementById("easy").checked == true) {
        spawnRate = 500;
    }
}

function startGame() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    baton = new batonPiece(50, 10, "28E060", 210, 250)
}

function ball() {
    this.x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30) + 15;
    this.y = 0;
    this.radius = 10;
    this.color = randomColor();
    this.draw = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = randomColor();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}

var balls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    balls[i] = new ball();
    balls[i].draw();
}

function batonPiece(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}

function randomColor() {
    var letter = "0123456789ABCDEF".split("");
    var color = "#";

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i = i + 1) {
        color += letter[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }

    return color;
}

function moveLeft() {
    batonPiece.x -= 1;
}

function moveRight() {
    baton.x += 1;
}

function stopMove() {
    baton.x = 0;
}
```

Comment: A very interesting title....

Comment: im sorry this is my first post haha

Comment: No issues mate. I am not well versed with canvas so wont be able to help on this but the title was too funny to ignore so just had to comment

Comment: neither am I haha , sadly